# Error in Spring MVC Program using netbeans

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

This is my first Spring Security project and I'm new to spring security. But I'm in a trouble with exceptions. Please help me to solve this
My POM.xml file

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0  http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.sarath01</groupId>
    <artifactId>WindowAuth</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>WindowAuth</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency> 
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.2.RELEASE</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.2.RELEASE</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.2.RELEASE</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>6.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    </project>
```

LoginController.java

```
    package com.sarath01.controller;

    import java.security.Principal;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

     @Controller
     public class LoginController {
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/welcome", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printWelcome(ModelMap model,Principal principal)
    {
        String name=principal.getName();
        model.addAttribute("username", name);
        model.addAttribute("message", "My first own mvc");
        return "hello";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/logout",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login(ModelMap model)
    {
        return "login";
    }
    
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/*",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(ModelMap model)
    {
        return "home";
    }

}
```

Spring-security.xml file

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      
    <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">
    
    
    
    <http auto-config='true'>
        <intercept-url pattern="/welcome*" access="ROLE_USER"/>
        <http-basic/>
    </http>
    
    
    
    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="sarath" password="123" authorities="ROLE_USER"/>
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
    
    </beans:beans>
```

auth-servlet.xm(Where auth is the servlet name)l

---

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   
      <beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
     xmlns:context = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
     xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">
     <context:component-scan base-package = "com.sarath01" />
 
    <bean class =  "org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name = "prefix" value = "/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
      <property name = "suffix" value = ".jsp" />
   </bean>

     <bean id="messageSource"   class="org.springframework.context.support.ResouceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basenames" value="mymessages"/>
      </bean>
    
    
    </beans>
```

web.xml

---

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <!--
     To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
     To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
     and open the template in the editor.
     -->
   <web-app id = "WebApp_ID" version = "2.4"
     xmlns = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
     xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    
      <display-name>MVC Auth Application</display-name>
      <servlet>
        <servlet-name>auth</servlet-name>
         <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>auth</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
     </servlet-mapping>
     <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/auth-servlet.xml
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter- class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

Exception (I cannit solve this exception)

---

```
        17-Jul-2018 16:36:36.358 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-8]   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop The stop() method was called on    component      [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/WindowAuth]    ] after stop() had already been called. The second call will be ignored.
          17-Jul-2018 16:36:36.858 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-8]   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.undeploy Undeploying context   [/WindowAuth]
          17-Jul-2018 16:36:36.901 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-2]    org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying    configuration descriptor /home/zeroone/.netbeans/8.2/apache-tomcat-    8.0.27.0_base/conf/Catalina/localhost/WindowAuth.xml
         17-Jul-2018 16:36:37.269 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-2] org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
         17-Jul-2018 16:36:37.303 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-2]   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.prepareRefresh   Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Jul 17 16:36:37 IST    2018]; root of context hierarchy
         17-Jul-2018 16:36:37.333 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-2]   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefiniti   ons Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/auth-   servlet.xml]
         17-Jul-2018 16:36:37.408 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-2]   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefiniti  ons Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-  INF/spring-security.xml]
         17-Jul-2018 16:36:37.417 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-2] org.springframework.security.core.SpringSecurityCoreVersion.performVersionChecks You are running with Spring Security Core 3.2.5.RELEASE
        17-Jul-2018 16:36:37.420 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-2] org.springframework.security.config.SecurityNamespaceHandler.<init> Spring Security 'config' module version is 3.2.5.RELEASE
        17-Jul-2018 16:36:37.438 SEVERE [http-nio-8084-exec-2] org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext Context initialization failed
           org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:     Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-   INF/spring-security.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:    org/springframework/security/web/util/matcher/AntPathRequestMatcher
            at    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:413)
            at       org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefiniti  ons(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:335)
```

Can any one please help me to find the answer or the error of this question? I'm a beginner to spring security

Comment: Any reason you use mix of different versions in your POM.xml?

Comment: @kkflf He's a beginner to Maven too.

Comment: He mentions that this is his first Spring-Security. He did not mention this was his first Maven project. That is how I read his post... Anyway, yes - the POM indicates he is new at using Maven.

Comment: @user3575472 I suggest that you use https://start.spring.io/ to generate a project with the proper versions.

Comment: @kkflf I didn't say it's his first Maven project, but are you claiming that's the configuration of someone who's experienced with Maven?

Comment: I do not make any assumptions nor do I claim anything. He only mentioned that this is his first Spring-Security project. There can be a numerous reason why he got a POM with mixed version numbers. And it doesn't matter if you said first or beginner to maven - that is more or less the same. Why do you even care to argue about if he is new to maven? It is besides the point. I asked him directly about the reason for the mix of version. He was free to answer that he was a beginner to maven or had a specific reason.

Comment: Never mix versions of a framework. For Spring you are mixing 3.0.0 and 5.0.2and Spring Security you are mixing 3.2.5 and 3.0.5. Align the versions of both Spring and Spring Security.

Answer (score 0):

`AntPathRequestMatcher` was introduced in version [3.1](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/util/AntPathRequestMatcher.html) of `spring-security-web`.

Please update POM.xml to a newer version of `spring-security-web`.

Comment: Ya I update it now it showing another exception   @kkflf

Comment: [org.springframework.context.support.ResouceBundleMessageSource] for bean with name 'messageSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/auth-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.support.ResouceBundleMessageSource

Comment: I encourage you to create a new application. And use Spring Boot version 2.0.3. You might want to consider use an annotation driven instead of xml driven project. You can find some decent Spring-Security guides here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/guides/html5/